# Less than and greater than 10

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a random code challenge, and I cannot figure out for the life of me how this would be possible

```
function(obj) {
   if ( (obj < 10) && (obj > 10) ) {
     return true;
   }
}
```

Things I've tried are setting an interval to change the variable at 0ms(which ends up being browser default), making obj an life function that increments a global variable every time it's used, and a whole bunch of other seemingly less useful approaches. Any ideas here, or pointers for something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: It wouldn't be allowed to be a code challenge if it wasn't possible, there's something being missed. Most likely some weird quark of JS that makes it possible somehow.

Comment: Name one number that would fulfill that criterion

Comment: And what makes you believe that people who create puzzles/code challenges never make mistakes? They are human after all

Comment: The fact that 488 people have completed it already

Comment: Could you link to the coding problem?

Comment: What makes you guys think that `obj` is a number?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The clue is in the variable name "obj". When objects are compared, their [`valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) method is called. If we supply a `valueOf` method that returns a different value every time:

```js
function test(obj) {
   if ( (obj < 10) && (obj > 10) ) {
     return true;
   }
}

var Obj = function() {
  var flag = false;
  
  this.valueOf = function() {
    if( flag ) {
      return 11;
    }

    flag = true;
    return 9;
  }
}

console.log( test( new Obj() ) );
```

The above object's `toValue` returns 9 the first time it's called (9 < 10) and 11 from then on (11 > 10).

Comment: Thank you, i knew i was missing something really simple. I tried using valueOf as well, but I didn't have the flag there to toggle between the 2 options.