# Is there any justification for `x < y && y > x`?

Tags: javascript, logical-operators, boolean-expression

I was going through some Javascript code used to validate form entry and I noticed an `if` statement that read `if (!(x < y && y > x)) {...}`

My initial thought was that this sort of tautological construction is completely redundant, and one of the two comparisons should be dropped. Just in case there's a chance I'm wrong and there's actually more to it, though, I thought I'd ask.

My other thought was that it might be a case of some idiom that is necessary in another language, which the programmer has here just brought along with them to Javascript out of habit (although I'd be surprised to find a language where something like this is required that is also used in any sort of environment).

EDIT

The specific code is in a function to test that the start and end dates for a submitted event are possible (i.e. the end date is after the start date). The actual example reads `if(!(start_time < end_time && end_time > start_time)) {...}` where both `start_time` and `end_time` are `DateTime` values.

EDIT 2

Not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322807/less-than-and-greater-than-10) as in this case the issue is the need to test two conditions that appear mutually inclusive in an `if` statement, whilst in that case the issue is how to make an `if` statement resolve that appears to require two mutually exclusive conditions to be simultaneously true.

Comment: It's *possible* to be not just tautological, but unlikely in a sane codebase. Can you post more of the code so we can see what `x` and `y` are?

Comment: Yes, please. Post some more code in context.

Comment: unable to understand your problem. however your code will never excute for this condition. it is just like == condition

Comment: @NegiRox Not necessarily. It's possible.

Comment: [Let's not forget, Javascript can be strange at times.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270127/can-a-1-a-2-a-3-ever-evaluate-to-true?rq=1)

Comment: If they're dates, then I'm *pretty sure* such a check is redundant.

Comment: At times like this, I would simply "fix" the code the way I see fit, putting in a `console.error` which prints if `(x < y) !== (x < y && y > x)`. Through the execution of your test cases you would see something in the logs if your assumptions are incorrect.

Comment: @CertainPerformance it is not possbile bro. if value are not same. this code will not execute

Comment: @NegiRox See the link posted by NisargShah. It *is* possible.

Comment: @NisargShah We also have some [really wonky coercion rules](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/) that might play a role in this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Less than and greater than 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322807/less-than-and-greater-than-10)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a pattern to allow falsy values, which convert to a number (without `NaN`, like `''` or `null`).

```js
function f(x, y) {
    return [!(x > y && y < x), x <= y, x < y || x === y].join(' ');
}

console.log(f(1, 2));                 //  true
console.log(f(2, 1));                 // false
console.log(f(1, 1));                 //  true
console.log(f('', 1));                //  true
console.log(f(1, ''));                // false
console.log(f('', ''));               //  true
console.log(f(undefined, undefined)); //  true \
console.log(f(1, undefined));         //  true  different values by using other comparisons
console.log(f(undefined, 1));         //  true /
console.log(f(null, null));           //  true
console.log(f(1, null));              // false
console.log(f(null, 1));              //  true
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```